# R merge rows with equals minimum value and keep the first element of a column and last of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where each row has an ID, and activity values. Below is an example dataframe :

```
test=data.frame(
start=c(1,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,100,150,200),
end=c(50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,150,200,250),
sub_id=c("subid_1_1","subid_1_2","subid_1_3","subid_1_4","subid_1_5","subid_1_6","subid_1_7","subid_1_8","subid_1_9","subid_1_10","subid_1_11","subid_2_1","subid_2_2","subid_2_3"),
id=c(rep("id_1",11),rep("id_2",3)),
activity=c(-0.2,-0.6,-1,-1.2,-1.6,-1.6,-0.5,0.2,-1.2,-0.8,0.1,0.1,1.2,0.5))




print(test)
       start end     sub_id   id activity
    1      1  50  subid_1_1 id_1     -0.2
    2     50 100  subid_1_2 id_1     -0.6
    3    100 150  subid_1_3 id_1     -1.0
    4    150 200  subid_1_4 id_1     -1.2
    5    200 250  subid_1_5 id_1     -1.6
    6    250 300  subid_1_6 id_1     -1.6
    7    300 350  subid_1_7 id_1     -0.5
    8    350 400  subid_1_8 id_1      0.2
    9    400 450  subid_1_9 id_1     -1.2
    10   450 500 subid_1_10 id_1     -0.8
    11   500 550 subid_1_11 id_1      0.1
    12   100 150  subid_2_1 id_2      0.1
    13   150 200  subid_2_2 id_2      1.2
    14   200 250  subid_2_3 id_2      0.5
```

For each rows which have the same ID :

I merged all the rows not separated by a value > -1 that are close to the min activity value. And kept the first value of start and last value of end for the merged rows and mean computed on the selected rows.

I did this like :

```
library(dplyr)

threshold <- -1

test.group <- test %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(activity > threshold)) 

print(test.group, row.names = F)

test.result <- 
  test.group %>%
  subset(activity <= -1) %>%
  group_by(id, grp) %>%
  arrange(activity) %>%
  summarise(
    start.min = first(start),
    end.min = first(end),
    sub_id.min = first(sub_id),
    activity.min = first(activity),
    start = min(start), 
    end = max(end), 
    activity = mean(activity)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(start, end, id, activity, start.min, end.min, activity.min)
```

My problem is that I cannot have min(start.min) and max(end.min) of consecutive min(activity).
I always display the min activity of a region. But How can I do it if I have 2 equals min value?

Expected output:

```
start   end id    activity start.min end.min activity.min
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>            <dbl>
1   100   300 id_1      -1.2       200     300          -1.6
2   400   450 id_1      -1.2       400     450          -1.2
```

Comment: what is activity column in the otuput?

Comment: mean(activity) of subid which have activiti < -1

Comment: Are you sure mean(activity) for the first row of output is -1.2 (instead of -13.5)??. I find the solution, but it returns -1.35  (average of -1, -1.2, -1.6, -1.6), not -1.2. Your script also gives -1.35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table::rleid` to create groups, remove rows where `activity <= -1` and find the relevant numbers in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  group_by(gr = data.table::rleid(activity <= -1)) %>%
  filter(activity <= -1) %>%
  summarise(start_1 = first(start), 
            end_1 = last(end), 
            id = first(id),
            activity_1 = mean(activity), 
            activity.min = min(activity), 
            start.min = min(start[activity == activity.min]), 
            end.min = max(end[activity == activity.min])) %>%
   select(-gr)

#   start_1 end_1 id    activity_1 activity.min start.min end.min
#    <dbl> <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     100   300 id_1       -1.35         -1.6       200     300
#2     400   450 id_1       -1.2          -1.2       400     450
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It works well. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%

  mutate(separated = activity <= -1,
         group = cumsum(c(1, diff(separated) != 0))
         ) %>%

  filter(separated) %>%

  group_by(id,group) %>%
  mutate(avgact = mean(activity),
         minact = min(activity),
         start0 = ifelse(activity == minact,start,NA),
         end0 = ifelse(activity == minact,end,NA)
         ) %>%

  summarise(start = first(start),
            end = last(end),
            act = mean(activity),
            start.min = min(start0, na.rm=T),
            end.min = max(end0, na.rm=T),
            activity.min = min(activity)
            ) %>%

  rename(activity = act)


# A tibble: 2 x 8
# Groups:   id [1]
#   id    group start   end activity start.min end.min activity.min
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 id_1      2   100   300    -1.35       200     300         -1.6
# 2 id_1      4   400   450    -1.2        400     450         -1.2
```